# With this MOSFET driver IC, is the output voltage range 0 to Vin or 0 to Vcc?

Tags: driver

I am using this driver IC, [ZXGD3005E6TA](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/ZXGD3005E6-95719.pdf). I am using a Pi as my controller, which has an output of 3.3V. The Vcc of my system is 12V.

I cannot determine if the IC will output the 12V when I supply 3.3V at the Vin pin or if it will only match the Vin and output 3.3V on the source pin - while still providing higher current.

How will this IC actually behave?

Comment: 0..Vcc -> Vin is just a signal

Comment: Thanks, if that is the case I was not able to find on the datasheet what the threshold voltage for Vin is. Will the 3.3V from the Pi be enough to trigger the source to 12V?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It wouldn't work as the driver needs Vcc-0,8 before it switches.

You can use the MCP1406/07 as it is much more versatile.

Remember when you're using a MOSFET driver, that you must place a decoupling capacitor between Vdd and GND (the MCP1407 has two Vdd pins) and a low ESR 0.1 uF electrolyt capacitor between Vdd and GND, to deliver the charge quickly.

On the input place a pulldown resistor.

:)

Comment: I believe that info on the table indicates that when Vin = Vcc that the output voltage will typically be Vcc-0.8. Not that the triggering voltage is Vcc-0.8. Similarly that the output voltage when low will be at most Vee+0.5. I will look at that other driver and see if it may work better for my application. Thank you.

Comment: The datasheet for the ZXGD3005E6TA is very hard to decode. 

I tried looking for a PSpice model without any luck. :)

Comment: I looked at MCP1407 and decided to use it for my design. The datasheet is much more detailed and clearly works with TTL level input. Thanks again.